# We have a 4 sided die, a 6 sided die and a 12 sided die. We roll a die twice and get 1 and 5. What's the probability that we rolled the 6 sided die?

Tags: probability, discrete-distributions

I'm trying to solve this question but I'm not sure about my thinking.

So I think what I need to compute is : $$P[\text{rolled the 6 sided die} | \text{got numbers 1 and 5}]$$

I tried to do it with the following formula : $$\frac{P[\text{rolled the 6 sided die AND got numbers 1 and 5}]}{P[\text{got numbers 1 and 5}]}$$

and I found the probability to be 4/5. Anyone that can share how to effectively solve this type of problem ?

Comment: You can't solve it with just the information given.  You need to specify the probabilities with which each of those dice is selected, and then you can apply Bayes' Theorem.  Your solution is tantamount to supposing the d6 and d12 are chosen with equal probability.  What, then, is the issue?  How to solve problems with insufficient information?  How to solve some kind of die-related problems?  How to adopt prior distributional assumptions? Please tell us what you mean by "this type of problem."

Comment: Hello @whuber, thanks for you answer. You are right, I'm a newbie and my question was unclear. I was assuming that d4, d6 and d12 are chosen with equal probability. In the formula of conditional probability I used, the numerator I calculated it to be 1/3 * 1/6*1/6 (1/3 being to probability of select d6). And the denominator, I used partition theorem but it felt weird : P(1,5) = P(1,5 AND d4) + P(1,5 AND d6) + P(1,5 AND d12) = 0 + 1/3*1/6*1/6 + 1/3*1/12*/12 

My issue was : is my thinking correct ? I just wanted to see how an experienced person would solve the problem

Comment: If you're rolling d4, you can't get a 5 at all, so you can exclude that case

Comment: @barrycarter I think it would be useful to let the full calculation show that. Somewhere, there’s going to be a probability of the d4 given the roll of a five, which will be taken as zero.